# How to use Resharper's Structured Search to add a new div which is 3 levels deep?

Tags: resharper

For example, in the below html, find all `div` tags with `class` equal to `bar` and also have a parent `div` equal to `foo`.

```
// leave this code alone
<div class="bar">
  Hello World!
</div>

// Do a structured find and replace on this code only
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    Hello World Again!
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the resharper search pattern I'm using and it produces no results:

```
<div class="foo"><div class="bar">$content$</div></div>
```

The replace pattern should add an additional, nested div with a class of baz:

```
<div class="foo"><div class="bar"><div class="baz">$content$</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Based on the available details you provided, I made an answer. Try to provide a screenshot if you still didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems correct.  It worked for me, for example define the pattern like this

[image: Before]

Use replace and we get

[image: After]

Comment: I tried this pattern with hours with no luck, but today it worked!!!??
Either I did something wrong... Or, my theory is that I needed to restart VS and rebuild the Resharper cache after I did my first replace in order for it to work. Maybe my second replace didn't work because it was searching the Resharper cache for code that didn't exist in the cache?

Comment: Glad you got it working in the end.  I guess something odd was going on like you say.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for your search pattern not to work.

This is your code

```
// leave this code alone
<div class="bar">
  Hello World!
</div>

// Do a structured find and replace on this code only
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    Hello World Again!
  </div>
</div>
```

and you tried with

```
<div class="foo"><div class="bar">$content$</div></div>
```

If you still can't match the search

#### Make sure you changed the Search Pattern to HTML

[image]

#### Try to change the search pattern in proper format as shown below (which may be a hard case. But you can try)

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    $content$
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Alternatively you can try

```
<$tag$ class="foo">
  <$tag$ class="bar">
    $content$
  </$tag$>
</$tag$>
```